# Subsonic 3 t4 template fails to compile

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I've downloaded Subsonic 3 from the website.

I added a connnectionstring section to my webconfig and updated the settings file as suggested on the website.

When It builds the code The Context.cs errors with the following:
[image]

All the other classes that it's built look ok. The correct table names are there etc. I'm sure this is a noob type question.. so I'm hoping an easy one for a subsonic guru out there.

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "DPR." prefixing your constructors is wrong.

Look at the line that declares the DatabaseName variable, it's line 26 in my copy.  Does it look like this?

```
const string DatabaseName = "DPR.RecordUpdateTaskCollector";
```

(the SS3 templates append "DB" onto whatever name you provide)

If so, just remove the "DPR.".  If you need that as the namespace, the correct spot is a few lines up where the "Namespace" variable is declared.

Comment: Got it.. so it doesn't support Dots in database names.. that clears it up..   I'll change to underscore :)